# Passing object as parameter when starting spring batch job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

My service is starting spring batch job. I want to be able to pass some object to the job, each time this object parameter will be different. This object I need to use in my tasklet.
I am starting the job by JobLauncher. As far as I googled, I see that JobParameters wont' help me in this case.
Also I found that lots of answers are to use JobExecutionContext or whatsoever. But I want to inject parameter object right before job start.
Is it posssible?

Service which starts the job

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Job myJob;

    @Override
    public MyResponse startJob(InputParameter inputObject) {
        try {
            //Here I want to pass somehow inputObject ot JobExecution
            jobLauncher.run(myJob, new JobParameters());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new MyResponse("FAILED")
        }
        return new MyResponse("OK");
    }
}
```

My Tasklet

```
@Component
@Scope("step")
public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet{

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        InputParameter inputObject = chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("inputObject");
        //... the main logic
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need to inject a complex object into your tasklet you have to init your complex bean in `JobExecutionListener`.If `InputParameter` can be resolved as a job parameters supported types (eg Long, String, etc) I raccomended you to switch to one of this supported types

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci could you please share any example regarding passing object via JobExecutionListener?

Comment: Usually this problem is solved wiring complex object in tasklet as a normal bean or if this object needs to be created based on current context use a service/dao to create object from context (usually a set of simple properties is enough). Simple properties can be passed as job parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Use the below class to send CustomObject.

```
public static class CustomJobParameter<T extends Serializable> extends JobParameter {
        private T customParam;
        public CustomJobParameter(T customParam){
            super("");
            this.customParam = customParam;
        }
        public T getValue(){
            return customParam;
        }
    }
```

===========================

Usage:

Sending parameter:

```
JobParameters paramJobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addParameter("customparam", new CustomJobParameter(myClassReference)).toJobParameters();
```

Retrieving parameter:

```
MyClass myclass = (MyClass)jobExecution.getJobParameters().getParameters().get("customparam").getValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do to pass params to a Job:

```
JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
builder.addString("fileName", fileName);
builder.addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis());
String jobParam = request.getParameter("job");
jobLauncher.run(myJob, builder.toJobParameters());
```

Comment: I suppose OP wants a "complex object" to be passed as parameter and not a "simple type" like String, Long, Int, etc...

Comment: yes, @Luca Basso Ricci is right, I need a complex object...thanks for response anyway

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot take the properties of the "complex object" and pass them to the job using the JobParamatersBuilder?

Comment: The object is too complex and used in tasklet methods as it is. converting fields to primitives and parsing them back doesn't look good... So if there is an alternative way, it will be good to try it at first turn.

Comment: Serialize / deserialize?   Pass a key to load from the database (assuming your object is persisted)?