# Maintain pre-job object through Spring Batch job steps

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-batch, autowired

For my batch application, I have a handful of steps I need to take prior to the execution of the Spring Batch job.  For  instance, I need to do a specific query and store data in a property - a List with a complex type (`List<ComplexType>`) - so that it can be used and manipulated throughout the Spring Batch job (primarily in the ItemReader).

I've tried autowiring in my list and accessing it in the step, but I can't access the data in the list that way.  I get a null ComplexType in my List, no matter what values have been added to my autowired List property prior to the job.

I have also tried [passing data using ExecutionContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps), but I don't think this is supposed to work outside the Spring Batch job execution.

**What I want to know, is what is the best way to populate an item prior to executing a Spring Batch job and maintain that object throughout the lifecycle of the job.**

If the best way is  one of the previous attempts I've made, any guidance on common mistakes with those approaches are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680189/passing-object-as-parameter-when-starting-spring-batch-job.
Check the comments in question,not the answer

Comment: store whatever you need to store in job listener (@BeforeJob) and inject it into reader... don't try and overcomplicate your life :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Luca Basso Ricci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587166/luca-basso-ricci) for the `JobExecutionListener` pointer.  I ended up creating my own `StepExecutionListener` where my pre-step processing would happen.

I followed [this example from Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-listeners-example/) which goes over different types of Spring Batch Listeners.

I created a custom listener like this one in the Java code:

```
public class CustomStepListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // initialize customObject and do other pre set setup
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
```

And I initialized the autowired `CustomObject` class here.  The `CustomObject` class is a custom object that simply contained my `List` of type `ComplexType`.

```
@Component
public class CustomObject {

    private List<ComplexType> customObjectList;

    public List<ComplexType> getCustomObjectList() {
        return customObjectList;
    }

    public void setCustomObjectList(List<ComplexType> customObjectList) {
        this.customObjectList= customObjectList;
    }
}
```

Finally, in my job configuration 'batch-job-context.xml' I added my new listener:

```
<!-- ... -->
<beans:bean id="customStepListener" 
        class="com.robotsquidward.CustomStepListener"/>

<job id="robotsquidwardJob"
    job-repository="jobRepository"
    incrementer="runIdIncrementer">
    <step id="robotsquidwardStep">
        <tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="1">
            <chunk 
                reader="robotsquidwardReader" 
                processor="robotsquidwardProcessor"
                writer="robotsquidwardWriter"
                commit-interval="1"/>
        </tasklet>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="customStepListener"/>
        </listeners>
    </step>
</job>
```

When I followed these steps I was able to initialize my `ComplexObject` `List` within the `beforeJob` function and access the values of the `ComplexObject` `List` within my job's Reader class:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "step")
public class RobotsquidwardReader implements ItemReader<ComplexType> {

    @Autowired
    private CustomObject customObject;

    @Override
    public ComplexType read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
            ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if(customObject.getCustomObjectList() != null) {
            return customObject.getCustomObjectList.remove(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Easy as that.  All it took is two new classes, a config change, and a major  headache :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :)
try to do this in job parameters incrementer trick :

```
<j:job id="Your_job"  incrementer="incrementerBean">
```

and

```
<bean id="incrementerBean" class="com.whatever.IncrementerClass"/>
```

incrementer class :

```
class IncrementerClass implements JobParametersIncrementer { 

  @Override
  JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {

    Map<String, JobParameter> map = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>(
    parameters.getParameters());
    ...
    //you can put here your list, if it can be :
    // Domain representation of a parameter to a batch job. Only the following types
    // can be parameters: String, Long, Date, and Double.

    //make some query 

    List<String> listStrings = Query.getYourQuery();

        //Join your query into string to have something like this below

        map.put("listOfSomething", new JobParameter("abc, abc, abc"));
        ...

     return new JobParameters(map);
  }


}
```

And thats all, 
then you can use this parameter for example in some processing bean :

```
  @Value("#{jobParameters['listOfSomething']}")
  private String yourList
```

You can build your list from string, and thats all :)
good luck

Comment: and if Your list is complex type which can not be converted to String, Long, Date, or Double, you have to write your own bean with job / step scope with this list storage.